# Trouble after implementing AdMob

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services

I've implemented AdMob as suggested on the [official guide's Google](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) but after that, the app starts to get stuck.

Both with my custom script and the original one give me the same result.

Function through I create the AdView:

```
    public View adMob_showCreateAdBanner()
    {

        AdView adView =   new AdView( context );
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewLayoutParams    =   new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        //viewLayoutParams.addRule( RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM );
        viewLayoutParams.addRule( RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL );
        adView.setLayoutParams( viewLayoutParams );
        adView.setAdSize( AdSize.BANNER );
        adView.setAdUnitId( "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" );

        adView.loadAd( new AdRequest.Builder().build() );

        return adView;
    }
```

and how I call it in my activity:

```
( (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.adSpace ) ).addView( cl_utility.adMob_showCreateAdBanner() );
```

Also `MobileAds.initialize(this, cl_utility.adMob_getPublisherID() );` that I call in the splash screen makes the activity getting stuck.

The LogCat doesn't help that much indeed...

```
03-02 12:34:09.405 1141-1141/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1141: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
03-02 12:34:09.848 1505-1529/system_process E/WindowManager: Performed 6 layouts in a row. Skipping
```

Any help please?

Comment: have you tried to include the `AdView` directly inside your xml?

Comment: Yes I've tried. The problem looks to be AdMob library. Without "MobileAds.inizialize" or any call to its library everything works fine. Whenever I write "MobileAds.inizialize", the app stops working in that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the *main activity* was `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`. Now everything works.
Thank you.